# How do they test COVID-19 in drive-thru labs?

Tags: covid-19, test, pcr

I've read that SARS-CoV-2 virus which causes COVID-19 disease can be tested with RT-qPCR.[1] It seems a somewhat lengthy procedure.

Then it's unclear to me: how do they test the virus in drive-through clinics in Daegu, South Korea?[2] **Specifically, do they use RT-qPCR testing or is there a faster way to test the secretion for virus?**

Because "drive-through" normally implies that procedure is done on the spot. (Or do they only collect the samples in drive-through fashion, but the results come in later?)

Links:

- [1] https://www.assaygenie.com/sarscov2-covid19-detection-methods
- [2] https://www.channelnewsasia.com/news/asia/south-korea-drive-through-coronavirus-test-facilities-12477046

Answer (score 2):

I cannot answer about South Korea, but as far as other drive-in test stations are concerned the rules I've seen are:

- Call ahead to get checked whether testing is indicated, get issued a special testing number.
- Go there, get tested with the testing number.
- Go back home, get test result via mail.